# jQuery find inside selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looping through divs, i'm tring to write a selector to get the uls, and do something for each of them.

My HTML (simplified) looks like this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <ul>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    </ul>
    ...
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <ul>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    </ul>
    ...
</div>

...
```

after this:

```
variable=$(.foo);
```

that of course works fine,
now i'm tring to do something like

```
for(var k=0;k<variable.length;k++){
variable[k].find('ul').doSomethingWithThese
}
```

but the selector is somehow wrong.
Even if my attempts were made on a simplified code, like the one in the example, the code is much more complex than this,
(inside my divs there is a lot more going on, and i'm building a loop with a map() function that for every div extracts something and concatenates with something else, and prints everything somewhere else...)
so please understand i can't just go like $(".foo > ul"), and even if i could i want to understand why my other attempts fail.

I tried every thinkable variant in the last 3 hours, including:
using children() instead of find(), using get(0) insted of [0], using get(0) or [0] after ('ul') (to try at least to get the first ul),
using $variable, $.(variable), ($.('ul')), ($('ul')), using each() instead of a for loop, creating variables for everything,
all the combinations possible of all of the above, google, stackoverflow, api.jquery.com...
than i tried even more simplified:

```
variable[0].children('ul')
variable[0].children('ul')[0]
```

and all the variants, and still no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `variable[k]` or `variable.get(k)` with a JQuery object it will give you the underlying DOM object and not a jQuery object. You can use the [.each method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop over each element and then wrap it back into a jQuery object or continue using your for loop and wrap.

.each

```
variable.each(function(index,element){
   var jqElement = jQuery(element); //or jQuery(this);
   var uls = jqElement.find("ul");
   uls.each(function(index2,ulElement){
      //do stuff
   });
});
```

For Loop

```
for(var k=0;k<variable.length;k++){
   var jqElement = jQuery(variable[k]);
   var uls = jqElement.find('ul');
   //etc
}
```

Of course you could just use a single selector to get the uls straight away

```
uls = jQuery(".foo ul");
uls.each(function(index,ulElement){
   var jqUL = jQuery(this);

   //if you need a reference to the parent .foo
   var parent = jqUL.closest(".foo");

   //etc do stuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks, very complete answer :)$

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.foo ul').each(function(){
 //do whatever you want
})
```

For detailed use of the jQuery each() function, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.each()` function

```
$('.foo').each(function(){
    var foo = $(this);
    var uls = foo.find('ul'); 
});
```

or

```
$('.foo ul').each(function(){
   //code...
});
```

or

```
$('.foo').each(function(){
    var foo = $(this);
    var uls = $('ul', foo); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `variable.each` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ to iterate over the items returned by the first selector. You will also want to change `.foo` to `'.foo'`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery returns an array like object, which contains DOM elements that match your selector (if any).
In your case 
`variable=$(.foo);` Is equivalent to `[<div class="foo"></div>, <div class="foo"></div> /* ... */]`

Since your for loop is iterating over the DOM elements in that returned array. You can either re-wrap the element as a jQuery Object like so:

```
for(var k=0;k<variable.length;k++){
   $(variable[k]).find('ul').doSomethingWithThese
}
```

Or use `$.each` to iterate over your collection:

```
$.each(variable, function () {
  $(this).find('ul').doSomethingWithThese
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo">
    <ul class='myClass'>
        <li>list 1-1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>list 1-2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>list 1-3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <ul>
        <li>list 2-1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='myClass'>
        <li>list 2-2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>list 2-3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.foo ul').each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('myClass')){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    } 
})
```

**Working Example**

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wo9j1746/)

Comment: Thanks,
i thought of this, this "hacks" around the problem but actually works ;)